# HTML 4 Iframe with HTML5 content

Tags: html, iframe, xhtml-1.0-strict

So i have another question. 
I made a page with a **xhtml1 doctype**.

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

And i put on that page a video element, and a form element thats using a placeholder. It would make sense to me that the video and placeholder wouldnt load/be recognized because i dont use a HTML5 doctype.

**However, the opposite is true, its loaded as html5.**

To add to that, i created an iframe in the xhtml1 page. I was wondering, what would happen if i would put an HTML5 page as a source inside that iframe. Concluding, it also loads as html5.

However, how can i make sure that the xhtml1 page doesnt load html5, and the iframe html5 page does?

I assumed the **difference was the doctype**, but maybe its **something else**? Browser? Or is there a repost somewhere making the browser initialize it as xhtml1, loading the iframe with html5, and returning the entire page as html5?

**Does someone have information about this? And possibly a way to solve it?**

Thank you for your help! :)

Ps:
1x xhtml1 page with iframe. (should only load xhtml1)
1x html5 page placed in the iframe. (should load html5)
If everything is too confusing, i will post small code sampled to illustrate the problem. Just tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the type of content you put in header has nothing to do with the browser parsing the tags.
so if your html code has html5 tags, they will be executed as normal.

i don't see any way to stop this except by manually checking with code.

Comment: alright, thank you for your answer! Ill wait if someone else might have a clue as to what to do :)

Comment: sure, but i understood you want the content to run it inside a iframe.
why would u want to restrict it in playing in the main home page

Comment: Hmm, actually, you just gave me the answer. I will explain it for you. I dont have any control over anything except the iframe. Meaning that what they do on that page doesnt matter.

Comment: Whoops, clicked enter. I mean that if it isnt doctype dependant that my problem is solved. I can just use html5 tags, because they will render as HTML5, unless the browser doesnt support it. Thanks!

Comment: cool :) [when u press enter, u can click edit, use shift+enter while typing]

Comment: haha, thanks! Gotta get used to it, i usually just press enter for next line, so... A habit :)