# HTML5 iframe in HTML4 document

Tags: html, browser, compatibility, incompatibility, html4

Is it possible to include iframe with HTML5 format inside HTML4 document?
Then, will HTML5 features work as expected? 
Or, will root document restrict the HTML5 features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `doctype` declaration will not restrict the elements if the browser needs to support the element.

https://html5test.com/results/desktop.html
 Source: [HTML 4 Iframe with HTML5 content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724828/html-4-iframe-with-html5-content)

So, answering your questions:

- Yes it is possible to do this.
- Yes all features will work, if the browser supports it.
- No there will be no restrictions because of the document.

Comment: Thanks! I thought there was no post on this. Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 0):

Normally, it will be. Frame rendering is independent of the parent page, so I think you will be able to load almost any page, even HTML5, in a frame on a root page with an older !DOCTYPE.